# c# дан массив, создать из него массив из уникальных элементов

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы, сортировка, for

дан массив, создать из него массив из уникальных элементов
выдает в строчке уникальные элементы, как сделать массив из этих элементов, не знаю.
хотел сделать это в простых циклах без использования библиотек, может, кто знает, как это сделать ? здесь кусок кода, где просто на консоль выдается 8, 12, 14 не в массиве.
в итоге должен получиться массив {8, 12, 14}

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int[] array = new int[7] { 5, 8, 5,10,10,12,14 };
        int countUnique = 0;
        int counter = 0;
         /* каждый элемент сравнил с элементом массива
        если совпадение равно 1, элемент не повторяется */
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
                if (array[i] == array[j])
                    counter++;
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                countUnique++;
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Уникальных элементов: " + countUnique);



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: списки проходили? можно использовать, или строго только массивы?

Comment: списки не проходил, хотел только массивами обойтись, три дня уже голову ломаю

Comment: пока еще в процессе)

Comment: @aepot
  вроде работает, можете глянуть? те еще спагетти получились

Comment: Вы как бы вообще не заметили мой ответ и комментарии. Ну ок, не надо, так не надо.

Comment: @aepot  списки не проходил
в описании добавил, что без библиотек, думал это про одно и то же

Answer (score 0):

создал массив на количество уникальных элементов, потом каждый
элемент проверил на уникальность еще раз, и если он повторяется
один раз, то включил в новый массив. вроде работает

```
int[] uniqueArray = new int[countUnique];

int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueArray.Length; i++)
{
    for ( ; k < array.Length; k++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[k] == array[j])                    
                counter++;                     
        }
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            uniqueArray[i] = array[k];
            k++;
            break;
        }                    
    }
}
```